# Comparar dos objetos con varios campos -ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una duda que seguro es fácil, pero no lo veo. Tengo un **ArrayList** que guarda unos jugadores de baloncesto. Cada jugador al crearlo tiene los siguientes campos, por hacer más visual la pregunta:

```
team1.addPlayer(new Player("Roberto","Dueñas Hernández", "Dueñas", LocalDate.parse("01/11/1975", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")), Country.ES, 35,400,3,team1,2,219,127,84,Position.C));
```

Ahora bien, necesito meter un código para *eliminar un jugador* de esta lista.

```
    public void removePlayer(Player player) throws TeamException{
    List <Player> squad = getSquad();
    boolean removed = false;

    if(squad!=null && player!=null) {
        for(int i = 0; i<squad.size() && !removed; i++) {
            if(squad.get(i)==player) {                  
                squad.remove(i); //Quitamos al jugador del equipo
                player.setTeam(null); //Al jugador le quitamos el equipo
                removed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!removed) throw new TeamException("[ERROR] The player you want to remove does not exist in your team!!");
}
```

Me gustaría saber como debería hacer la comparación entre los elementos que tengo guardados en mi **ArrayList** y un elemento que meta por parámetro en el anterior código. El código del cual llamo al método **removePlayer** sería:

```
team1.removePlayer(new Player("Roberto","Dueñas Hernández","Dueñas", LocalDate.parse("01/11/1975",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")),Country.ES,35,400,3,team1,2,219,127,84,Position.C));
```

¿Como puedo eliminarlos? ¿Como puedo hacer la comparación?

PD: Uso **ArrayList** y no **LinkedList** ya que apenas habrá inserciones/eliminaciones en el programa y constantemente se usarán *consultas(get)*.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Comment: Agregué una respuesta pero considera agregar tu objeto Player, tal vez no tienes getter o setter, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes un objeto `Player` el cual tiene como propiedad el nombre, puede usar esa propiedad para realizar la comparación, por ejemplo debes tener un `getter()` que obtenga el nombre del jugador en el objeto, y de esta forma si son iguales al realizar la comparación de los nombres mediante `equals()`, eliminarias el objeto de la lista.

```
 //if(squad.get(i)==player) {     
  if(squad.get(i).getNombre().equals(player.getNombre())) {   
      squad.remove(i); //Quitamos al jugador del equipo
      player.setTeam(null); //Al jugador le quitamos el equipo
      removed = true;
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió!

Answer (score 1):

Si tiene una clase `Player`, lo que puede hacer es implementar los métodos `hashCode()` e `equals()`, y en el metodo `equals()` modifica los campos que quiere comparar y que a su criterio hacen que un jugador sea único. Si trabaja con eclipse sobre la clase `Player` da click derecho selecciona la opción `Source --> Generate hashCode() and equals()`, se abre una ventana y selecciona los campos por los cuales quiere definir cuando un jugador es igual a otro, eclipse crea el código.
Ahora la implementación seria algo así:

```
public Boolean removePlayer(Player player){
  return this.squad.remove(player);
}
```

retornara `true` si el jugardo existe y se removio ó `false` si no.

Coloco `this` asumiendo que es un atributo de alguna clase `Team`.